Power Automate - When an email arrives to a group - Create email file and upload to SharePoint
I have a requirement to create a flow that will create a file out of an email, create a folder in SP, and place that file in that folder.  This triggers after any email is sent to a Group mailbox.  Since it's not a Shared Mailbox, the trigger action "When a new email arrives in a Shared Mailbox" doesn't trigger.  So I'm using the trigger action "When a new email arrives to a group".  The way I have this set up does everything I want, except that it doesn't gather the Email subject, body, or attachments.  


Like I said, it does 90% of it correctly: Triggers when an email is sent to that Group, creates a folder in SP, creates a file, and uploads that file to that new folder.  However when I open the file from SP, the contents of the email are blanks, and there's no attachment.  Could someone please let me know what Actions I should add to get the email Subject, Body, and Attachments?
Thanks!
